# Drawing a two lens system using pst-optic

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to draw a two lens system using `pst-optic`. Here is an example of the code I use :

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-3)(7,4)
\rput(0.0,0.0){\lens[lensType=CVG,lensGlass=true,lensWidth=0.4,lensHeight=5,rayColor=red,focus=2,AB=2,OA=-4]}
\Transform
\rput(4.0,0.0){\lens[lensType=CVG,lensGlass=true,lensWidth=0.4,lensHeight=5,rayColor=red,focus=2]}
\end{pspicture}
```

According to the [manual](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-optic/pst-optic-doc.pdf), this should work. Nevertheless, I get an error. I work with Overleaf.

With only one lens, it works fine :

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-3)(7,4)
\rput(0.0,0.0){\lens[lensType=CVG,lensGlass=true,lensWidth=0.4,lensHeight=5,rayColor=red,focus=2,AB=2,OA=-4]}
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: It works for me with miktex.

Comment: Did you include only \usepackage{pst-optic}?

Comment: This is what I used and `pdflatex`ed it: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optic}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-3)(7,4)
\rput(0.0,0.0){\lens[lensType=CVG,lensGlass=true,lensWidth=0.4,lensHeight=5,rayColor=red,focus=2,AB=2,OA=-4]}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: This works also for me. What I cannot get without error is the first MWE (two lens).

Comment: That too works for me. I can't include that code in comments. It's too long.

Comment: It's working with TeXShop. I don't know what happens with Overleaf...

Comment: I suppose that overleaf always uses pdflatex without the option `shell-escape` for running `latex` in te background.